# Finding the Probability from the sum of 3 random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Let $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ be three independent normal random variables having mean $\mu= 0$ and variance $\sigma^2=16.$

Compute $P(X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2>8).$

*Hint:* First transform the random variables to standard normal.

I transformed the random variables to $Z$ standard normal and got $Z_1=X_1/4,\, Z_2=X_2/4$ and $Z_3=X_3/4.$ I am unsure about where to go from here.

I know that the sum of random variables is the same as the product of their moment generating functions but how do I apply that here?

Comment: The distribution of square of standard normal is chi-square. The sum of independent chi-square is still chi-square.

Comment: Can I find the distribution of one random variable since it is just chi square?

Comment: I am still confused as to where I can apply this, since we know it is chi-square distribution could I find the distribution of Z random variable and find the pdf from that, then the probability with 3 degree of freedoms since there are 3 random variables?

Comment: I see that you say chi square with $3$ degrees of freedom, so seems you somehow have the concept, but not sure which part you confused. I do not state all the things explicitly because that will be a spoiler. Can you state which variable has what distribution clearly and what confusion do you have now?

Comment: So what I did was I found the distribution of Z(1)^2 by finding the distribution of it which came out to be the chi square distribution which I then plugged in by saying P(3Z^2>1/2)=P(chi square>1/6) since Z^2 is chi square, then after rearranging terms I found the probability to be .975. This is just Z1 so I am confused how to find the probability of the sum of the 3 variables.

Comment: Since I used the three degrees of freedom would this probability I just found be my probability of the sum of the three random variables?

Comment: Why you say $Z_1^2 + Z_2^2 + Z_3^2$ has the same distribution as $3Z^2$? Those three random variables are independent, they are not the same variable. As you said the sum is just a chi-squared random variable with 3 degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested outline.

(1) Use MGFs (or a transformation method) to show that each of the three $Z_i,$ for $i=1,2,3,$ has a chi-squared distribution with $1$ degree of freedom.

(2) Use MGFs to show that $Q = Z_1^2 + Z_2^2 + Z_3^2$
has a chi-squared distribution with $3$ degrees of freedom.

(3) Use software or printed tables of the distribution $\mathsf{Chisq}(df=3)$ to evaluate (or approximate) $P(Q > 0.5).$

Using R statistical software, I get about 0.9189.
(Depending on the printed tables available, you may be able to say only that the answer is between .90 and .95.)

```
1-pchisq(.5, 3)
[1] 0.9188914
```

In the figure below, the desired probability is represented by the area under the density curve to the right of the vertical red line at 0.5.

[image]

*Note:* A simulation in R, accurate to two or three places.

```
set.seed(1024);  m = 10^6
x1 = rnorm(m, 0, 4)
x2 = rnorm(m, 0, 4)
x3 = rnorm(m, 0, 4)
s = x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2
mean(s > 8)
## 0.918736
```

Comment: This problem relates to practical issues as well as learning about chi-sq dist'n: If data are normal, then the sample variance $S^2$ estimates the population variance $\sigma^2$ and the relationship $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2 \sim $ CHISQ$(n-1)$ provides a confidence interval for $\sigma^2.$